# Simple example of ListView run time error

Tags: android, listview

I am new in android, I want to test a simple example of List view but it has a run time error, I try to fix it on my own but I really didn't understand the problem exactly.
I expect this program show me an activity with a listview that contains the str variables.

```
package ir.mohad.listf;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;


 public class Main extends ListActivity {


public static final String[] str = new String[]{"ali","mohammad", "hasan", "hossein", "taqi"};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, str));
}
```

}

and here is my xml file :

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"     
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"   
tools:context=".Main">
<ListView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: In the future, please post the stacktrace of the crash with your post.

Comment: Hi, please show me the answer of my question, I didn't find it here :(

Comment: Change the id of your ListView. If that doesn't fix your problem (which it should) then you need to post the errors

Comment: Thank you, It fixed :)
the point was id : @android:id/list
not id : @+id/list